# Google suggestion above algolia autocomplete

Tags: algolia

i've try to use Algolia today for my website, work perfectitly but the google suggestion always show in front of the input before the results of Algolia. [image: Example]
So if you have any idea (I already try do desactivate this but without any results )
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to deactivate the chrome suggestion dropdown, you should add `autocomplete="off"` to your search input

`<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion